# Game crashes on Android after using AdMob with Google Play Games Services

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services

I use unity , google play game services (last version 0.9.64) works good in my game when used without AdMob , but when i added AdMob (last version 3.18.0) when i download my game from google play store and click the open button there it show this error "app name has stopped" but the game still work in background i can play it normal and i can open it from the phone widget without that error but this error appears again if i click a button in my game to Sign in to google play services , Ads works good

- i tried google game services old version 0.9.53 with AdMobe new version 
  3.18.0 everything works good i can sign in to gpgs and ads works but the 
  error "app name has stopped" still appear when only game opened from google 
  play store

i may use the oldest versions of gpgs if it's the only way to make that work but whats the solution for the error "app name has stopped" i still get when game opened from the store ?

Logcat when gpgs and admob last versions are used and i opened the game directly from google play store after downloading it and the ""app name has stopped" error appears :

```
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:211)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Kadev.HungryyBears-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Kadev.HungryyBears-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    07-09 20:32:20.903: E/Unity(2689):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadCla
```

Logcat when gpgs and admob last versions are used and i click sign in to gpgs button then the same error appears :

```
07-09 20:10:12.633: W/Unity(31914): OnLevelWasLoaded was found on Reporter
07-09 20:10:12.633: W/Unity(31914): This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.
07-09 20:10:12.633: W/Unity(31914): Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed
07-09 20:10:12.633: W/Unity(31914):  
07-09 20:10:12.633: W/Unity(31914): (Filename:  Line: 356)
07-09 20:10:18.273: I/Unity(31914): Ads Request Created
07-09 20:10:18.273: I/Unity(31914):  
07-09 20:10:18.273: I/Unity(31914): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
07-09 20:10:25.003: I/Unity(31914): HandleAdLoaded event received
07-09 20:10:25.003: I/Unity(31914):  
07-09 20:10:25.003: I/Unity(31914): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
07-09 20:10:32.073: I/Unity(31914): Starting Auth with token client.
07-09 20:10:32.073: I/Unity(31914):  
07-09 20:10:32.073: I/Unity(31914): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
07-09 20:10:32.103: W/Unity(31914): !!! [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/09/19 19:10:32 +00:00 WARNING: Creating new PlayGamesPlatform
07-09 20:10:32.103: W/Unity(31914):  
07-09 20:10:32.103: W/Unity(31914): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for GPGS 0.9.64 and AdMob 0.18.0 is in player settings check proguard option and that will creat an empty proguard file in plugins/android folder open it in Visual Studio and past that code (suggested by SlobodanNikolic in Github website https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/598):

```
-dontwarn com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
-keep class com.google.unity.** {
   *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontobfuscate
```

with this solution above you ll still have the first time game opened from google play crash message .
but after some days they released a new version of AdMob 0.18.1 that works good with GPGS 0.9.64 without this problems.

Answer (score 0):

-You can solve this problem by following below instruction.Go to

Assets -> Play services resolver -> Android -> Force Resolve

-If above instruction doesn’t work then You have to follow below instruction,

Player Settings -> Publishing Settings -> set release and debug in minify option to “None”.

Similar issue :
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1464677/admob-plugin-error-javalangclassnotfoundexception.html

Comment: thanks for your answer but i tried  Force Resolve but didn't help and for minify option is on None